# SQLite give me an error near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I create DbManger Class to handle Sqlite database Operation,i try to insert value in database it give an error

> E/SQLiteDatabase(6729): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO CREATE TABLE relations(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL, age TEXT NOT NULL, location TEXT NOT NULL);(email,name,age,location) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

DbManager Class

```
public class DBManager {

    int rowsAffected;

    // Database and version
    private static final String DB_NAME = "familyHistory";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_INFO = "familyTable"; 

    private static final String _ROWID = "_id";
    private static final String _NAME = "name";
    private static final String _EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String _AGE = "age";
    private static final String _LOCATIONs = "location"; 

    private static final String CREATE_PRO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INFO + "(" + 
            _ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            _NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            _EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            _AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            _LOCATIONs + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private final Context ourContext;
    private static DBHelper ourDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public DBManager(Context ctx) {
        this.ourContext = ctx;
        Log.i("db", "DBManager(Context ctx)");
    }

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            // SQLiteOpenHelper Constructor Creating database
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            Log.i("db", "DBHelper(Context context)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_PRO);
            Log.e(">>>>>", CREATE_PRO);
            // db.execSQL(CREATE_TRVLBOK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVer, int newVer) {
            Log.w("Nomad", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVer + " to " + newVer
                    + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INFO);
            // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TRAVELBOK);
            onCreate(db);
            Log.i("db", "onUpgrade)");
        }

    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        ourDBHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i("db", "open()");
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourDBHelper.close();
        Log.i("db", "close()");
    }



    public long insertFamRec(String UserName, String Email, String age, String location) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(_NAME, UserName);
        cv.put(_EMAIL, Email);
        cv.put(_AGE, age);
        cv.put(_LOCATIONs, location);
        Log.i("db", "insertLocRec");
        return ourDatabase.insert(CREATE_PRO, null, cv);

    }
}
```

And from insertion class i added these line but still error

```
DBManager db = new DBManager(NewRelation.this);
    db.open(); 
    long i = db.insertFamRec("strfullName", "stremail", "strage", "strlocation");

    db.close();
    if (i > 0) {
         ShowMessage.Message(NewRelation.this, "data is added");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data is failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

if somebody give down rating of question please mention it why .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues seems to be where you call `ourDatabase.insert`, you pass the query string in the place of a table name. What do you hope to achieve with this line: `return ourDatabase.insert(CREATE_PRO, null, cv);`?

Change the line to :

```
return ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_INFO, null, cv);
```

Note, instead of `CREATE_PRO`, I pass `TABLE_INFO` which is the name of the table you are inserting into.
I hope this resolves your problem. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ishmael i forgot! the disadvantages of copy paste :P :)

Comment: Copy-and-paste can be costly! I am glad I was able to help, please vote the answer if you find it useful.